# Possible to access remote EJBs from a custom LoginModule?

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I found some nice hints on how to write a custom realm and loginModule. I'm wondering though if it is possible to access a remote EJB within the custom loginModule.

In my case, I have remote EJBs that provide access to user-entities (via JPA) -- can I use them (e.g. via @EJB annotation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself: works fine! I can get a reference to the remote SLSB via an InitialContext.

Here's the code:

```
public class UserLoginModule extends AppservPasswordLoginModule {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    private UserFacadeLocal userFacade;

    public UserLoginModule() {

        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            userFacade = (UserFacadeLocal) ic.lookup("java:global/MyAppServer/UserFacade!com.skalio.myapp.beans.UserFacadeLocal");
            log.info("userFacade bean received");

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            log.warning("Unable to get userFacade Bean!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void authenticateUser() throws LoginException {
        log.fine("Attempting to authenticate user '"+ _username +"', '"+ _password +"'");

        User user;

        // get the realm
        UserRealm userRealm = (UserRealm) _currentRealm;

        try {
            user = userFacade.authenticate(_username, _password.trim());
            userFacade.detach(user);

        } catch (UnauthorizedException e) {
            log.warning("Authentication failed: "+ e.getMessage());
            throw new LoginException("UserLogin authentication failed!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new LoginException("UserLogin failed: "+ e.getMessage());

        }
        log.fine("Authentication successful for "+ user);

        // get the groups the user is a member of
        String[] grpList = userRealm.authorize(user);
        if (grpList == null) {
            throw new LoginException("User is not member of any groups");
        }

        // Add the logged in user to the subject's principals.
        // This works, but unfortunately, I can't reach the user object
        // afterwards again.
        Set principals = _subject.getPrincipals();
        principals.add(new UserPrincipalImpl(user));

        this.commitUserAuthentication(grpList);
    }

}
```

The trick is to separate the interfaces for the beans from the WAR. I bundle all interfaces and common entities in a separate OSGi module and deploy it with `asadmin --type osgi`. As a result, the custom UserLoginModule can classload them.

Comment: Yes. I want to see your code. I need to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Code added. By now I'm not using this approach anymore even though it worked as expected. However, I found deployment in a clustered environment too complicated. Instead, I'm now using a simple `ResourceFilter` in front of REST resources that require authentication. Much simpler, all in the same WAR.